# Sumif formula on row determined by a criteria within column

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have been trying to create a formula that decides whether a row matches a criteria, and then sums data in the row based on a second criteria. I have tried my luck with `LOOKUP`,`VLOOKUP`, `HLOOKUP`, and `INDEX`, but have not figured out a correct formula. The most common error I get back is `#Value` when the sum would take place.

Example:

[image: Example 1]

[image: Example 2]

Let's say that the formula is in Q2. The formula needs to be able to match up A123 with the row A-123-4 (A2) and then sumif the row as long as the cells in that row are within the proper month `MONTH($B$11:$I$11)=1`

What I made initially was this:
`{=SUM(IF(MONTH($B$11:$I$11)=1,$B2:$I2,0))}`

The problem is that both of these are tables, so if the information gets rearanged using a filter, the data shifts. How can I get the formula to determine which row is the proper row to sumif?

Comment: Are the values in B11:I11 true dates formatted `mmm` or are they string text?  Same with the ones in Q:AB?

Comment: yes both are formatted

Comment: Will it always be 1 to 1 rows or will the row need to return many rows?

Comment: will always only need to return one row

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use This in Q2 and copy over and down:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(INDEX($B:$I,MATCH(LEFT($P2) & "-" &MID($P2,2,LEN($P2)) & "*",$A:$A,0),0)*(MONTH($B$11:$I$11) = MONTH(Q$1)))
```

[image]